# Copy file from one server to another

Tags: java

I need to copy a text file from one server to another (both the servers are Linux).
How do I do that in Java?

Comment: type of server ? , can server B access server A's file using HTTP ?

Comment: Can you use FTP? Are your servers on the same network? Are you using a Shared File System? Can you deploy a Servlet? I think we would need more background to answer.

Comment: You *can* use [scp](http://www.go2linux.org/scp-linux-command-line-copy-files-over-ssh), but I guess your'e after implementing it yourself, no?

Comment: The answer to this strongly depends on what transport mechanisms you have available.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to copy files from accessible file systems go with [Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812673/copy-file-from-one-server-to-another/3812705#3812705).

If you want a general approach that abstracts from the protocol underneath, have a look at [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/). It provides a common api for resources available through [a number of protocols](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html):

- FTP
- Local Files
- HTTP and HTTPS
- SFTP
- Temporary Files
- Zip, Jar and Tar (uncompressed, tgz or tbz2)
- gzip and bzip2
- res
- ram
- mime

Answer (score 4):

Easist if you're able to use [apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/): the [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFileToDirectory-java.io.File-java.io.File-) class has convenient methods to copy files:

```
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, targetDirectory);
```

(as you talked about text **files** I assume, your application has access to both file systems)

Comment: Would require that server A has a directory of server B mounted locally?

Comment: Guess so. The question is somewhat vague - usually you have a given interface (file system, ftp, webservice, ...) and look for help to implement/use it with a given programming language (here: Java)...

Answer (score 1):

If you go with FTP, you could use the FTPClient from Apache commons/net.

Here are some sample codes for your reference:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect(host);

if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode())) {
  if(client.login(username, password)) {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(localFilepath);

    try {
      if(client.storeFile(remoteFilename, fis)) {
        System.out.println("File uploaded!");
      }
    }
    finally {
      fis.close();
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all linux machines will be having SSH server running by default. So SCP would be your best bet to copy files between them.

Use a SSH library like JSCH to do this. You will find a tutorial to do SCP transfer using JSCH [here](http://seancode.blogspot.com/2008/02/jsch-scp-file-in-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way and your server supports PHP, I recommend the [Rapid Transfer Script](http://www.rapidtransferscript.com).

Just upload the script to the directory you want to copy the file to, enter the URL of the file you want to copy and click *Transfer*. It copied a 1.4GB file across in under 2 minutes and saved me a lot of time and bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I have used commons net FTP to transfer file from one server to another.

Maven Dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;


    public void tranferFile() {

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(servername, port);
            ftpClient.login(username, password);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            File sourceFile = new File("file which you want to send");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

            boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile("filename which receiver get", inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            if (done) {
                LOGGER.info("file is uploaded successfully..............");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occured while ftp : "+e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception occured while ftp logout/disconnect : "+e);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you connect to the other server? Because I only see one FTPClient connected. Can you explain please?

Comment: Sibtain Hi, servername is your hostname or IP and port will be your FTP port running on server and username/password to connect server.